# How can I fix Windows 10 start menu and taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

In a couple days ago the Windows start menu is stopped working on my computer and the right click menu not show, when I make right click a task bar icon.

1. I don't have restore point so I can't make restore.
2. I ran SFC/SCANNOW commmand the result was: "Windows resource protection did not find any integrity violations"
3. I tryed reinstall metro apps with this command:

   > Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage
   >   -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

   I no get error message, the command was successfully executed but didn't fix anything.
4. I tryed reinstall windows updates follow this command:

   > DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

   But seams like doesn't work either.
5. I maked a new user and logged in to that account, but the start menu and task bar right click menu still not worked, the problem still the same.

At this point  I gived up, unestly I have no idea why I have this problem after many, many fixing methods.
I need help, I don't would like to reinstall my Windows is so painful.

Comment: "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" isn't a command to reinstall Windows.  My suggestion use the Reset feature within Windows 10 to solve this problem

Comment: @Ramhound I think you misreading something I said:
I tryed reinstall **windows updates**

Comment: That command doesn't reinstall Windows Update either.

Comment: It does in powershell look after in this article:
http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/has-your-windows-10-start-menu-stopped-working-here-are-four-ways-to-fix-it-11364000314532

Comment: The article indicates it will repair your Windows installation, not reinstall Windows or reinstall Windows Update, you used the word "reinstall" which has specific meaning when it comes to Windows ( for instance Reset/Refresh features both reinstall Windows ).

Comment: ***This will download files from Windows Update to replace the corrupt ones ***
I think it's pretty clear what it does in this case the reinstall is not too far world.

Answer (score -2):

This bug occur because has invalid sets of permmissions on regedit: HKEY_Current_User; and invalid permissions on %UserProfile% (here set your current user owner)  and %ProgramData% (reset to defaults)

Comment: You should explain to the author in detail, how they can reset their ACL, for their %UserProfile% and %ProgramData% directories.

Comment: I gessed out thx the direction, but It's dosen't worked.
I need to restart windows explorer after?